# Replace placeholder in text file with user input

Tags: php, string, file, replace

I have a string that comes from an android application. I also have a file (unknown.txt) which contains a line "20,30,40,2,5,?". I want to write a PHP script which is called by the android application that replaces the "?" in the line with the string from the app and places the new string after replacing the "?" in another text file(data.txt). I know how to send the string from the app to the server. I want to know how to perform the string manipulation to achieve this.

```
<?php
//get string from app
$dev=$_POST["devicename"];

//read unknown.txt and fetch string
$file = 'unknown.txt';
$fh = fopen($file,'r');
$data = fread($fh,filesize($file));
fclose($fh);

//need code to replace "?" from $data with contents of $dev
```

Comment: Do you know about the `str_replace` function?

Comment: A quick google yields [php string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: If it is always the last character perhaps `fread($fh,filesize($file) - 1);` - then append `$dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) of `str_replace():`

> str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int
>   &$count ] )

For your specific use case:

```
//read unknown.txt and fetch string
$file = 'unknown.txt';
$fh = fopen($file,'r');
$data = fread($fh,filesize($file));
fclose($fh);

// replace "?" from $data with contents of $dev
$data = str_replace('?',$dev,$data);
```

You also could use `preg_replace()`, but that seems like using an ax where a scalpel is needed.

Using `preg_replace()`:

```
$data = preg_replace('#\?#',$dev,$data);
```

Also, regular expressions tend to be a little slower compared to native PHP functions. But it's good to know your options.

Comment: That should do it, apart from knowing any attack vectors in the potential $_POST activity.

Comment: You bring up a very good point: Always sanitize untrusted content and use prepared statements when interacting with the database.